# Is it possible to export an iOS Framework binary to a static library?

Tags: ios, static, frameworks

We are using a 3rd party Framework in our iOS app and now have a need to create a new Framework to abstract this framework.  My understanding is that Frameworks cannot contain other Frameworks.  Is there a method to convert? I've been googling this for days, any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar question. I'd like to create a Swift SDK that wraps an Obj-C binary framework (exposes Headers only), and somehow hide that fact to users of the SDK.

Comment: I pursued this for a couple weeks on and off and it's not possible.